# Trouble looping child nodes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have XML in the following way

```
<categories>
   <category id="1">abc</category>
   <category id="2">eev</category>
   <category id="3">adf</category>
   <category id="4">ggt</category>
</categories>
```

I want to loop all children of `<categories>` and get the id and text and load it in select box

My JQuery looks like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('getCategoryHandler.ashx', function (d) {
        $(d).each(function (index) {                                                            
            var opt = '<option value="' + $(this).attr("id") + '">' + $(this).text() + '</option>';
            $("#catOptions").append($(opt)).trigger("chosen:updated");                                                            
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

With this I get all the text in one shot and not in a loop

I used find('category') but it is very slow and takes nearly 10 seconds for 15 category node (in IE 11)

What's wrong with the script i have?

Comment: What is the format of the response you set in the `d` variable?

Comment: d is [object XMLDocument]

Comment: Yes, but what is within that XML?

Comment: How can I print d? I'm fairy new to Jquery (writing on my own)

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan I think you should parse the data first. Have a look here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: I did alert($(d).text); and got this
`function(a){return V(this,function(a){return void 0===a?m.text(this):this.empty().append((this[0]&&this[0].ownerDocument||y).createTextNode(a))},null,a,arguments.length)}`

Comment: `text()`, not `text`, and use `console.log`, not `alert` (you can read the console using F12)

Comment: @DenysSéguret Thanks for the syntax. I get all the text values only from the child node

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'd' is your entire XML Categories node. you need to loop through the children not the "categories" node itself. Also the '$.each()' function offers 2 parameters. The index and the object itself. Use it. Note the 'child' parameter.

Also you are looking for the attribute 'uuid' but your xml that you pasted here only had the attribute 'id'. make sure you are pulling the correct attributes.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('getCategoryHandler.ashx', function (d) {
        $(d).children().each(function (index, child) {                                                            
            var opt = '<option value="' + $(child).attr("id") + '">' + $(child).text() + '</option>';
            $("#catOptions").append(opt).trigger("chosen:updated");                                                            
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregg-Duncan for the answer. Unfortunately the loop stops at one iteration and I get all the text() in one <option>. Code behaves same way as in my question. find() is consuming good 15 seconds for a small XML file.

Comment: Are you sure it's the find() that is consuming all the time and not your .ashx call? This fiddle works on the xml file you posted in milliseconds. http://jsfiddle.net/3o6h3khp/1/

Comment: Yes. Even with a static XML with find it takes good 15 seconds to process 30 nodes